# Moq and Find Expressions - Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, linq, moq

I'm fiddling with Moq and I can't figure out why the following proof-of-concept snippet is throwing a `NullReferenceException` when accessing `mock.Object.SingleOrDefault`:

```
var myObject = new MyObject() { Id = 1, Name = "Name" };
var mock = new Mock<MyInterface<MyObject>>();
mock
    .Setup(t => t.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>>>()))
    .Returns(myObject);

var mySecondObject = mock.Object.SingleOrDefault(a => true);
Assert.AreEqual(myObject, mySecondObject);
```

Any clues?

Comment: You haven't setup `SingleOrDefault`, why do you expect to return something different to null? Did you mean to use `Find`?

Comment: I tried that, but got another exception:

NotSupportedExceptoin: "Additional information: Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object:"

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Mock can only setup virtual instance members on the type (in this case on `MyInterface<>`). But `SingleOrDefault` is a Linq extension method. Either it is `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault` or `Queryable.SingleOrDefault` static method, most likely.

Comment: Why do you think `SingleOrDefault` will lead to your `Find` method? The interface `MyInterface<>` cannot contain any functionality that provides that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your MyInterface inherits IQueryable.
Then, when you call SingleOrDefault on that, it calls IQueryable.Provider property on the instance provided.

Since you have not mocked IQueryable.Provider property, it returs null from a mock, so you've got a NullReferenceException.

Try to set MockBehavior.Strict to see if that's the cause.